# How to filter using aws CLI to match ec2s started in a range of dates for a string value which contains a date like StateTransitionReason?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, automation, aws-sdk, aws-cli

I'm trying to make a monitor script which will look for old ec2 boxes started, not launched, older than 7 days and they remain in stopped status and then delete them. For that, I need to identify those unused boxes. The LaunchTime value is a date parameter but the parameter I'm trying to use is StateTransitionReason and it contains a date.

This works and show me a complete list:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters 'Name=instance-state-name,Values=stopped'  'Name=tag:App_Name,Values=MYAPPS' 'Name=tag:Name,Values=development-*' --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].{Instance:InstanceId,StateTransitionReason:StateTransitionReason,Name:Tags[?Key==`Owner`]|[0].Value}'
```

But if I try this, it doesn't show me anything:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters 'Name=instance-state-name,Values=stopped'  'Name=tag:App_Name,Values=MYAPPS' 'Name=tag:Name,Values=development-*' --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[?StateTransitionReason<="User initiated (2019-10-10 05:00:00 GMT)"].{Instance:InstanceId,StateTransitionReason:StateTransitionReason,Name:Tags[?Key==`Owner`]|[0].Value}'
```

StateTransitionReason is a string param but it contains a date, is there a way to filter for earlier dates than a specific one?

I tried checking in the AWS documentation but it doesn't explain that.

Comment: Suggestion: It would be much easier to retrieve and parse such values by using a programming language (eg Python) rather than using the AWS CLI. (But your commands look very impressive!)

Comment: Thanks @JohnRotenstein :) , yeah, I was just giving a try if anyone could give me a clue. If not, I will be ending using a python function.

Comment: ```
#!/bin/bash

if date -v-30d > /dev/null 2>&1; then
    # BSD systems (Mac OS X)
    DATE=date -v-30d +%Y-%m-%d
else
    # GNU systems (Linux)
   DATE=$(date --date="-90 days" +%Y-%m-%d)
  echo $DATE
fi

aws ec2 describe-instances --filters 'Name=instance-state-name,Values=stopped'  --query "Reservations[].Instances[?LaunchTime>=\`$DATE\`][].{id: InstanceId, type: InstanceType, launched: LaunchTime,state: State,stat_transation: StateTransitionReason}"
``` but this based on LaunchTime

Comment: @Adiii I'm not looking for LaunchTime, I'm looking for the last time it was started as the ec2s are stopped automatically but started by developers. That's why I need StateTransitionReason

Comment: StateTransitionReason the failed not only contain time but also the reason so it some sort of string, you need to grab datetime for yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will seem silly but the reason is that you are using " instead of ` inside the query.
Try doing:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters 'Name=instance-state-name,Values=stopped'  'Name=tag:App_Name,Values=MYAPPS' 'Name=tag:Name,Values=development-*' --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[?StateTransitionReason<=`User initiated (2019-10-10 05:00:00 GMT)`].{Instance:InstanceId,StateTransitionReason:StateTransitionReason,Name:Tags[?Key==`Owner`]|[0].Value}'
```

It worked when I checked it.